# JSON Jersey Auto serialization Wrapper Problems

Tags: java, json, spring, jaxb, jax-rs

I have a POJO

```
public class Graph {
    public int v;
    public int e;
}
```

and a very simple service

```
@Service("graph-service#default")
public class DefaultGraphService implements GraphService {
    public Response createGraph(Graph graph) {
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

which implements a very simple interface

```
@Path( "graph-service" )
public interface GraphService {

    @Path( "create-graph" )
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createGraph(Graph graph);
}
```

I have a simple spring-context.xml set up as follows

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
       http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="me.jamesphiliprobinson.graphs"/>

    <jaxrs:server id="testServices" address="/testServices">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="graph-service#default"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>
    <bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
</beans>
```

If I spin the service up in tomcat it works fine can I can curl an object like

```
{"v":2,"e":1}
```

Without any difficulty. However, if I run this test

```
@Test
public void testCreateGraph() {
    UncertaintyGraphService service =
            JAXRSClientFactory.create( "http://localhost:" + port + "/" + getRestServicesPath() + "/testServices/",
                                       GraphService.class );
    Graph graph = new Graph();
    graph.e = 1;
    graph.v = 2;
    Response result = service.createGraph(graph);
    assertNotNull(result);
}
```

Then it fails as there is

```
No message body writer has been found for class : class me.jamesphiliprobinson.graphs.Graph, ContentType : application/json
```

If I add an

```
@XmlRootElement
```

to the POJO then the service serializes the graph object but seems to send

```
{"graph":{"e":1,"v",2}}
```

Instead which I can see making sense but the deserialization seems to still expect

```
{"e":1,"v":2}
```

As I get the error

```
WARNING: WebApplicationException has been caught : Unrecognized field "graph" (Class me.jamesphiliprobinson.graphs.Graph), not marked as ignorable
```

I'm surely missing something incredibly simple. I would prefer for the items to serialise to

```
{"v":2,"e":1}
```

But if they will deserialise correctly I can live with a root element. i.e.

```
{"graph":{"v":2,"e":1}}
```

Comment: Try to use the overloaded [`JAXRSClientFactory.create(String baseAddress, Class<T> cls, List<?> providers)`](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/JAXRSClientFactory.html#create%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.util.List%290), and add the `JacksonJsonProvider` to the `List` of providers

Comment: Im not 100% sure, (need some research) but i can give you some hints. It seems you are mixing Jackson along with native JAXB. My thinking on tomcat the context load with jsonProvider and parse accordingly. But in test its might not getting jsonProvider somehow, maybe another configuration needed for test context. 
so when you use @XmlRootElement its producing according to JAXB.

There are a bit difference among those  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28895761/jackson-vs-jaxb-what-is-better-for-json?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: http://codingexplained.com/coding/java/ignoring-unrecognized-json-fields-spring-jackson

Comment: @peeskillet - WOW! Please rewrite as an answer and I will add mark as correct. This has been killing me all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See where you are registering the `JacksonJsonProvider` on the server?

```
<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
```

This is to handle JSON (de)serizalization to/from POJO on the server side. But the client needs the same support. You can use the overloaded

- [`JAXRSClientFactory.create(String baseAddress, Class<T> cls, List<?> providers)`](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/JAXRSClientFactory.html#create%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.util.List%29)

to register the provider on the client side. Just add the `JacksonJsonProvider` to the `List` of `providers`.

```
JAXRSClientFactory.create(baseUri, Service.class, Arrays.asList(new JacksonJsonProvider())
```